# Cant access oracle.com from my home network only

Tags: networking, website, redirection

I can't access https://www.oracle.com from my home network only. Other sites are accessible.

I have cleared cache and checked the `hosts` file (there was nothing). The browser returns `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

[image]

Comment: Change your DNS provider.

Answer (score 0):

The `ERROR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error is generated when you try to load a page, which tells your browser to load another page, which tells your browser to load a third page, and so on (specifically, 20 times for Chrome).

From your screenshot, it looks like Oracle's website is trying to send you to an error page. Then, when you try to load the error page, another error occurs. That error makes the server send you to an error page for the error page, and you can guess what happens next.

Although strictly speaking this is an issue on Oracle's end, there are a few things you can try to see if the errors will stop. Follow these instructions to clear Chrome's cache and cookies:

1. On your browser toolbar, click More (the three dots button, AKA the burger menu).
2. Point to More tools, and then click Clear browsing data.
3. In the "Clear browsing data" box, click the checkboxes for "Cookies and other site and plug-in data" and "Cached images and files".
4. Use the menu at the top to select the amount of data that you want to delete. Choose beginning of time to delete everything.
5. Click Clear browsing data.

Comment: I have tried this, but error is absolutely same

Comment: Can the OP see this redirection somewhere, to shed more light on the issue ?